# What buld system is used in Android O

Tags: android, android-source

I found out that root directory contains both [make](https://github.com/google/kati) and [blueprint](https://github.com/google/blueprint) files. Also some projects (for instance `art`) contain both `Android.mk` and `Android.bp` files. But some projects contain only one of them `Android.mk` or `Android.bp`. So what build system is actually used? Is make build system deprecated?